# How to update this id ( relationship ) using typeOrm in nest js

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

how to update this `departmentId` means instead of this `id` set `updated id` that means this student have another relation. so how to do it. i try many thing but i didn't imagine how to do it.

***student.controller.ts***

```
@Patch(':studentId/remove')
    delete(@Param('studentId') studentId : number){
            return this.studentService.updateDepartment(studentId);
    }
```

***student.service.ts***

```
async updateDepartment(studentId: number) {
    // write the code here
  }
```

***student.entity.ts***

```
@ManyToOne(()=>Department, (department)=>department.students,{onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
    department : Department
```

***department.entity.ts***

```
@OneToMany(()=>Student, (student)=>student.department,{onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
  students: Student[]
```

***Current***

```
id  |  name  |  age  |  departmentId
1   | shreya | 23    |   2
```

***Expected***

```
id  |  name  |  age  |  departmentId
1   | shreya | 23    |   1
```

Answer (score 0):

first: get the department you want to change

```
const department = await Department.findOne(departmentId);
```

second: get a student from the old department:

```
const student = await Student.createQueryBuilder('student')
      .where('student.departmentId = :id', { id: oldDepartmentId }).getOne();
```

third: assign new department to student

```
student.department = department;
```

fourth: save the student

```
await student.save();
```